# Dynamically pivot n rows with new row for multiple values

Tags: excel, powerbi, pivot, powerquery

I wish to transform the input to the output shown below:

[image]

However for Columns D and K there are multiple values for D and K which causes and error:

[image]

**M Code to replicate the above:**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Column1]), "Column1", "Column2")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

I have also attempted to add an index column so that each data point is unique but this leads to further problems.

So far I have actually grouped the data so that everything is contained in a single cell:

**Current M Code:**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type1", {"Column1"}, {{"Column2", each Text.Combine([Column2],"#(lf)"), type text}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[Column1]), "Column1", "Column2")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

However this requires the data to be split which is fine but **I want to do this dynamically for n Columns i..e A-B or A-AZ and this kind of shifts the problems so that I have to dynamically Split n columns.**

**Input data:**

```
Column1 Column2
A   1
B   1
C   2
D   3
D   3
D   1
E   2
F   1
G   2
H   1
I   2
J   3
K   1
K   2
L   1
M   2
N   3
```

Comment: What about to group and append the multiple values as new columns instead of concat/combine, and then transpose instead of pivot?

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood I think the issue with this is that with the data I get, its unknown what values and therefore columns will necessarily be generated. So I need to avoid any manual correcting step.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer though because I would be interested to see how it can be done without a custom function!

Comment: Not as elegant as horseyride’s solution. Basically after grouping with Text.Combined split column2 dynamically into separate columns based on the max number items separated by delimiter. Then transpose and 1st row as header.

Comment: I hope it’s ok to post this link about split a column dynamically: https://eforexcel.com/wp/power-query-tips-tricks-6-split-a-column-dynamically-i-e-no-dependency-on-the-number-of-result-columns/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A not unusual problem solved by a custom function.  Check the link in the credits for an explanation:

***Custom Function***

```
//credit: Cam Wallace  https://www.dingbatdata.com/2018/03/08/non-aggregate-pivot-with-multiple-rows-in-powerquery/

//Rename:  fnPivotAll 

(Source as table,
    ColToPivot as text,
    ColForValues as text)=> 

let
     PivotColNames = List.Buffer(List.Distinct(Table.Column(Source,ColToPivot))),
     #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, PivotColNames, ColToPivot, ColForValues, each _),
 
    TableFromRecordOfLists = (rec as record, fieldnames as list) =>
    
    let
        PartialRecord = Record.SelectFields(rec,fieldnames),
        RecordToList = Record.ToList(PartialRecord),
        Table = Table.FromColumns(RecordToList,fieldnames)
    in
        Table,
 
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Values", each TableFromRecordOfLists(_,PivotColNames)),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",PivotColNames),
    #"Expanded Values" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Values", PivotColNames)
in
    #"Expanded Values"
```

***Main Code***

```
let

//change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table24"]}[Content],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}}),
    
    pivot = fnPivotAll(#"Changed Type","Column1","Column2")
in
    pivot
```

***Results from your data***
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work fine (a) group and add index inside group (b) expand (c) pivot

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Column1"}, {{"data", each  Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type), type table}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Column2", "Index"}, {"Column2", "Index"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded data", List.Distinct(#"Expanded data"[Column1]), "Column1", "Column2"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"Index"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Very elegant. Nice work.

Comment: Yeah this works great too!